# Lazy readonly "property" in Rust

Tags: rust

Given this struct in Rust:

```rust
struct OrderLine {
    price: f32,
    quantity: f32,
}

impl OrderLine {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        println!("total has been computed"); // this is used in the test bellow
        self.price * self.quantity
    }
}
```

How can I:

1. Compute the `total` value only once per instance of this struct, even when this function is called multiple times (please, see the test bellow for an example of the expected behaviour). The `total` value must be lazy calculated. I don't want it to be pre-computed when the struct is initialized, for example in an `OrderLine::new` function.
2. Maintain consistency between `total` and the underlining values (`price` and `quantity`):

   1. If we allow them to change, `total` must be recomputed the next time it gets called.
   2. Or, if that is not possible or too difficult, make this struct immutable to prevent changes.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_total_must_be_computed_only_once() {
        let order_line = OrderLine {
            price: 10.0,
            quantity: 2.0,
        };
        println!("before calling total for the first time");
        println!("{}", order_line.total());
        println!("before calling total for the second time");
        println!("{}", order_line.total());

        // The actual output is:
        // before calling total for the first time
        // total has been computed
        // 20
        // before calling total for the second time
        // total has been computed                  <- repeated
        // 20

        // The expected output is:
        // before calling total for the first time
        // total has been computed                  <- no repetition
        // 20
        // before calling total for the second time
        // 20
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `RefCell` or `Arc` for interior mutability.

Comment: For a `Copy` type, you can just use `Cell`. And when it gets stabilised, `OnceCell`, which is the best-suited for this purpose.

Comment: If you want it to recompute each time `price` or `quantity` is changed, you're going to need to either cache their values when computing and recheck them on every call to `total`, or you'll need to access them solely through accessors that clear the cached value for `total` each time the setter is called. You'd need locking as well, to keep it thread-safe. It won't be pretty.

Comment: @FZs I don't think `OnceCell` is a good fit for this: the property has to be able to be invalidated and set to be recomputed. Imo `Option` is a better choice here.

Comment: `OnceCell` can easily be invalidated by just overwriting it with `OnceCell::new()`

Comment: @PitaJ Or using `OnceCell::take()`, but I agree `new()` is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate approach is to use a `OnceCell`. The benefit of this (vs the `Option` approach) is that is does not require `&mut self` access:

```rust
// in the process of being added to the standard library, but not there yet
use once_cell::unsync::OnceCell;

pub struct OrderLine {
    price: f32,
    quantity: f32,
    total: OnceCell<f32>,
}

impl OrderLine {
    pub fn new(price: f32, quantity: f32) -> Self {
        OrderLine {
            price,
            quantity,
            total: OnceCell::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        // calculate the total if not already calculated
        *self.total.get_or_init(|| {
            println!("COMPUTED"); // this is used in the test bellow
            self.price * self.quantity
        })
    }

    pub fn set_price(&mut self, price: f32) {
        self.price = price;
        // clear the previous calculated total
        self.total = OnceCell::new();
    }

    pub fn set_quantity(&mut self, quantity: f32) {
        self.quantity = quantity;
        // clear the previous calculated total
        self.total = OnceCell::new();
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ebd1d1af9ef3d6eb08bc250f9a8cbdf)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using an `Option`:

```rust
pub struct OrderLine {
    price: f32,
    quantity: f32,
    total: Option<f32>,
}

impl OrderLine {
    pub fn new(price: f32, quantity: f32) -> Self {
        Self {
            price,
            quantity,
            total: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn total(&mut self) -> f32 {
        *self.total.get_or_insert_with(|| {
            let total = self.price * self.quantity;
            println!("total has been computed"); // this is used in the test bellow
            total
        })
    }

    pub fn set_price(&mut self, price: f32) {
        self.price = price;
        self.total = None;
    }

    pub fn set_quantity(&mut self, quantity: f32) {
        self.quantity = quantity;
        self.total = None;
    }

    pub fn price(&self) -> f32 {
        self.price
    }

    pub fn quantity(&self) -> f32 {
        self.quantity
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_total_must_be_computed_only_once() {
        let mut order_line = OrderLine::new(10.0, 2.0);
        println!("before calling total for the first time");
        println!("{}", order_line.total());
        println!("before calling total for the second time");
        println!("{}", order_line.total());

        order_line.set_price(500.0);
        println!("before calling total for the third time");
        println!("{}", order_line.total());
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires a `&mut self` in `total`, which, I would think, is undesirable. If it's fine, then this is indeed the simplest way.

Comment: FYI the code in `fn total` is essentially `Option::get_or_insert_with`

Comment: @PitaJ: The contents of `total` could simplify to something like `self.total.get_or_insert_with(|| { println!("total has been computed"); self.price * self.quantity })` (without the print, it ends up fairly clean as `self.total.get_or_insert_with(|| self.price * self.quantity)`) correct? With a `*` prefix to deref I guess.